Unable to find taglib [s] for URI: [/struts-tags] in Intellij
I'm using a Struts project, and Eclipse for development, and my environment is set up correctly there. However, when I try to use IntelliJ, I encounter the error:
 "Unable to find taglib [s] for URI: [/struts-tags]."

I have already tried deleting the .m2 folder and running mvn install again or I tried placing the struts-tags.tld file from the struts2-core-2.3.37.jar into the root of the WEB-INF directory, but the error still persists.
How can I resolve this issue?
Tomcat: tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar
part of pom.xml:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity-tools</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>struts-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>struts-taglib</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>struts-tiles</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
                    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


You should post a code where were you encounting an error.

You shouldn't extract .tld files from the library struts2-core. This library should be added to your project as a dependency. Then clean and rebuild the project.
See how to Create Struts 2 Web Application Using Maven To Manage Artifacts and To Build The Application.
The pom.xml for core struts2 application requires only
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
    <version>X.X.X.X</version>
</dependency>

and it will download all other dependencies.
